# Determine reason for Xcode crash "std::length_error: basic_string::resize" with Unity-build game?

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

Recently the iPad game I'm developing in Unity started crashing when a particular level was opened. The game itself launches, I can navigate to the offending level, but when I attempt to load the level the following Xcode exception occurs:

***libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: basic_string::resize***

I tried adding a breakpoint and get the following additional info:
***warsides`std::basic_string, stl_allocator >::resize(unsigned long, char) at basic_string.tcc:629:***

Since I get no errors within Unity and none of this corresponds to anything in my C# scripts, I am at a loss as to how to track down the issue.

I would appreciate any help in either how to track down where the error is occurring or how to solve it. There is a lot of code and I don't know how to zero in on where/why this started happening.

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

The full crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 210674A1-10EB-47F4-A6FA-F787C4AEE0B6
CrashReporter Key:   f000ac896ec00a43627ab3130d809476f28d27dd
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:             warsides [238]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/E4D83D50-77BB-4F5A-96EF-A1F0E137575F/warsides.app/warsides
Identifier:          com.vladimirneykov.warsides
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-12 19:41:14.721 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  11

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaa58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eea854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed64896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed63002 __CFRunLoopRun + 850
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eccdf0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2eccdcee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x33bf365e GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x31619168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   warsides                        0x0008bdcc main (main.mm:28)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x39e47ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eea808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39e2c078 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39e2bdfe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   warsides                        0x01ca1a40 mono_sem_wait + 24
2   warsides                        0x01bfd654 finalizer_thread + 140
3   warsides                        0x01c7d520 start_wrapper + 496
4   warsides                        0x01c9a554 thread_start_routine + 284
5   warsides                        0x01cb66f0 GC_start_routine + 92
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39efbf44 __accept + 8
1   warsides                        0x01bbe578 transport_accept + 20
2   warsides                        0x01bbe9a4 debugger_thread + 240
3   warsides                        0x01c9a554 thread_start_routine + 284
4   warsides                        0x01cb66f0 GC_start_routine + 92
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   warsides                        0x01765480 Semaphore::WaitForSignal() (PlatformSemaphore.h:53)
2   warsides                        0x017d9e30 JobScheduler::WorkLoop(void*) (JobScheduler.cpp:152)
3   warsides                        0x017da9d0 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   warsides                        0x01d09980 algThreadJobQueueThreadFunc + 16
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   warsides                        0x01765480 Semaphore::WaitForSignal() (PlatformSemaphore.h:53)
2   warsides                        0x0171db78 SubstanceSystem::ThreadMain(void*) (SubstanceSystem.cpp:480)
3   warsides                        0x017da9d0 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   warsides                        0x01a37464 FMOD_OS_Semaphore_Wait(FMOD_OS_SEMAPHORE*) + 16
2   warsides                        0x01a4c2e8 FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 60
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaa58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eea854 mach_msg + 44
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2e7497f6 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 102
3   AudioToolbox                    0x2e74c8dc AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
4   AudioToolbox                    0x2e689fc0 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39efd544 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39e6e988 nanosleep + 168
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39e6e8d6 usleep + 46
3   warsides                        0x01a371b6 FMOD_OS_Time_Sleep(unsigned int) + 10
4   warsides                        0x01a4c2d2 FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 38
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eeaa58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39eea854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed64896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed62fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eccdf0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed119fe CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2f38b3a8 ___lldb_unnamed_function1423$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39efd1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f67792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39eadfd8 abort + 72
3   warsides                        0x01bba070 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 312
4   warsides                        0x01bd6da8 sigabrt_signal_handler + 104
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x39f61f90 _sigtramp + 40
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f67792 pthread_kill + 54
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39eadfd8 abort + 72
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x391dccd2 abort_message + 70
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x391f56aa default_terminate_handler() + 194
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3993af86 _objc_terminate() + 226
11  libc++abi.dylib                 0x391f31c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
12  libc++abi.dylib                 0x391f2a18 __cxa_throw + 112
13  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x39c7982e std::__throw_length_error(char const*) + 266
14  warsides                        0x0174491c std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, stl_allocator<char, (MemLabelIdentifier)51, 16> >::resize(unsigned long, char) (basic_string.h:318)
15  warsides                        0x01744884 void StreamedBinaryRead<false>::TransferSTLStyleArray<UnityStr>(UnityStr&, TransferMetaFlags) (SerializeTraits.h:215)
16  warsides                        0x0177d1b4 void TransferScriptData<StreamedBinaryRead<false> >(TransferScriptInstance&, StreamedBinaryRead<false>&) (SerializeTraits.h:207)
17  warsides                        0x0177d630 void TransferScriptData<StreamedBinaryRead<false> >(TransferScriptInstance&, StreamedBinaryRead<false>&) (MonoBehaviourSerialization.h:35)
18  warsides                        0x0177cf90 void MonoBehaviour::TransferWithInstance<StreamedBinaryRead<false> >(StreamedBinaryRead<false>&, MonoObject*, MonoClass*) (MonoBehaviourSerialization.cpp:720)
19  warsides                        0x01776a20 void MonoBehaviour::TransferEngineAndInstance<StreamedBinaryRead<false> >(StreamedBinaryRead<false>&) (MonoBehaviourSerialization.cpp:702)
20  warsides                        0x017761cc MonoBehaviour::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead<false>&) (MonoBehaviourSerialization.cpp:790)
21  warsides                        0x017c4fb0 SerializedFile::ReadObject(int, int, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree**, bool*, Object**) (SerializedFile.cpp:1327)
22  warsides                        0x017bf208 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(std::string const&, int*, int*, int, bool, LoadProgress*) (PersistentManager.cpp:1447)
23  warsides                        0x01764a34 PreloadLevelOperation::Perform() (PreloadManager.cpp:649)
24  warsides                        0x017642bc PreloadManager::Run() (PreloadManager.cpp:231)
25  warsides                        0x017641ec PreloadManager::Run(void*) (PreloadManager.cpp:184)
26  warsides                        0x017da9d0 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66916 _pthread_body + 138
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f66886 _pthread_start + 98
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f64aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x0a26f1f0
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0a270000      r6: 0x00000006      r7: 0x0a26f1e8
    r8: 0x073a1e00    r9: 0x3bee1e30     r10: 0x174f13e4     r11: 0x11327f78
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x0a26f1dc      lr: 0x39f67797      pc: 0x39efd1f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: Can you attach the whole crash log?

Comment: Hey @golergka, sure, just edited my post to include everything Xcode was outputting. Would the breakpoint info also be helpful?

Comment: The text that you added looks like Unity debug output, it's not a Xcode crash log with full call stack. You can read more about apple's crash logs here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for the link - very helpful! I edited my post to contain the crash log pulled directly from the iPad. I kept the Binary Images section out, it was too long to post, not sure if it would be helpful to have it as well.

Comment: Well, that's certainly a very uncommon crash. If it was your code, the crash would be in thread 1, where all mono logic resides, so it's certainly not it. Since there are signatures like `SerializedFile::ReadObject` and `PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded` in the call stack, it seems something's off with your data. May be you can check the strings that you have associated with that particular level and check what's wrong with them? May be some of them are unexpectedly long?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I ended up reverting to my old backup and adding one my one the updated elements until I came upon the culprit. I am still not 100% sure why it was causing this. The crash was caused by two public string variables I declared in a serializable class which was used in a few places as variables exposed to the editor. I felt that the strings will just start at a blank "" and not throw any errors (which was fine with Unity, but Xcode seemed to mind.) Anywho, after a few days on this, it was remedied just by filling out the exposed string variables with some text content.